# How to use DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.DesktopConsumer.RequestUserAuthorization with url contaqins port?

Tags: magento, url, port, dotnetopenauth, magento-1.8

i have:

```
            var service = new ServiceProviderDescription
            {
                RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint( this._requestTokenUrl, this._requestTokenHttpDeliveryMethod ),
                UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint( this._authorizeUrl, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest ),
                AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint( this._accessTokenUrl, this._accessTokenHttpDeliveryMethod ),
                TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() },
                ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V10a, 
            };

            this._tokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager();
            this._tokenManager.ConsumerKey = this._consumerKey;
            this._tokenManager.ConsumerSecret = this._consumerSecretKey;

            this._consumer = new DesktopConsumer( service, this._tokenManager );

            this._accessToken = string.Empty;
                            consumer.RequestUserAuthorization( null, null, out this.requestToken );
```

when _requestTokenUrl equals for example 127.0.0.1:1234/magento - method throws an exception because server returns: 401 oauth_problem=signature_invalid

But if i use 127.0.0.1/magento  it works fine.

How to use RequestUserAuthorization() with URL that contains port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution not in DotNetOpanAuth but in magento. By default magento ignores port when calculating the signature in `Mage_Oauth_Model_Server::_validateSignature()`. To change it you must  pass the false parameter to the `$this->_request->getHttpHost()`. 
May be it will be possible [Magento Rest Oauth API (Signature Invalid) 401](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555514/3607337)